# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook

Tags: excel, apache-poi, runtimeexception

I use maven to manage my web project dependency. I add apache poi dependency into my pom file. it does not show error when complied. but when it runs, it will throw RuntimeException at my MainApplication() class. while it gives that java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook

I have a MainApplication class.

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
private Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
HashSet<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

public MainApplication() {
    try {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext springContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

        singletons.add(springContext.getBean("transformService", DataTransformService.class));
}

public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    return classes;
}

protected ApplicationContext springContext;

public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    return singletons;
}
```

}

Below is what i add

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
  <version>3.8-beta3</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.14</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/reportv2]] StandardWrapper.Throwable: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct public com.osg.application.MainApplication()
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:144) [:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:243) [:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:191) [:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:67) [:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36) [:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1208) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:955) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:188) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.0.0.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695) [:1.6.0_65]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_65]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2446) [:1.6.0_65]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1872) [:1.6.0_65]
at      org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:227) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:930) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:903) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at com.osg.application.MainApplication.<init>(MainApplication.java:19) [:]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_65]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_65]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [:1.6.0_65]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [:1.6.0_65]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:132) [:]
... 23 more
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Apache POI provides a components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) which details all of the different parts of the project, what jars you need, and what Maven artifacts you need. If you look there you'll see the following:

```
|Component | Application type   | Maven artifactId | Notes
|Common SS | Excel XLS and XLSX | poi-ooxml | WorkbookFactory and friends all require poi-ooxml, not just core poi |
```

As that clearly states, if you want to use all of the common `org.apache.poi.ss` classes, you need to depend on `poi-ooxml` and not just on `poi`

Secondly, compile time != run time. Just because a jar was sucked down by maven and made available to compile with, doesn't mean it'll be there when your code runs. You also need to ensure you package your dependencies with your code, or otherwise ensure they're on the classpath at runtime.

You seem (from the stacktrace) to be writing a web application, so you'll need to ensure that all your dependencies get put into the war in `/WEB-INF/lib/` so they're there at runtime.

Finally, POI 3.8 beta 3 is a very odd version to use. You should either go with the latest stable (right now 3.9), or the latest beta (right not 3.10 beta 2). See the [POI homepage](http://poi.apache.org/index.html) for details of the current releases.

Comment: thank you very much. I fixed my problem. I changed the scope from 'provided' to 'compile', then after i maven clean install, in my war package, there is poi jar existing in /WEB-INF/lib/. it works.